# SQL Server performance <>, NOT IN, IN

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have about 4.500.000 rows in a table.

`Status_code` can be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

Which query will run the fastest?

Query #1:

```
Select * 
from Table 
where status_code not in (1)
```

Query #2:

```
Select * 
from Table 
where status_code <> 1
```

Query #3:

```
Select * 
from Table 
where status_code in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: "It depends" , you should try to run it and measure ;)

Comment: It depends on the number of matching records, indexes on your table, the measurement you're doing (searching time? Retrieving time? Search and retrieve?)... The sun, the moon... Too broad

Comment: The first question you should answer is which one is most correct? Generally over time, the domain of things like "status" change. Values are usually added; rarely are they changed or deleted. So if we assume that the future will bring additional status values, which query best expresses your goal? And yes - [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1):

Without indexes, you are going to get an identical Table Scan operation for each of those so the cost will be identical.

As you then consider indexing, then the seek predicates may change slightly. 1 and 2 will usually be identical as it effectively introduces the same predicates (Status_Code < 1, Status_Code > 1). The predicates for 3 will be an equality check for each of the possible included values.

Whether this makes a difference overall depends - you'd need to see what the actual Execution Plans tell you.